# Oracle - unable to create DB link

Tags: oracle, dblink, sysdba

I am unable to create the DB link as it's throwing ORA - 01031 insufficient privileges error.
Let's say I have database DB1 and schema name as s1 and second database as DB2 with schema t1.
I am trying to create the DB link by sysdba user by running below -

```sql
alter session set current_schema=s1;
Create database_link dblinkname connect to t1 identified by password using DB2;
```

But this is giving me error. I tried giving privileges also to s1 but no luck. Any leads. I don't have the schema password for s1 and I can't reset it as it's production environment.

Comment: DB links *must* be created by the owner of the link. You cannot create a database link directly in another schema, even as SYSDBA. You must login as `s1` or work around things as suggested by RobertG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a several years ago.

Assuming, you don't want to create a public database link...

You can do this:

1. Grant privilege create database link to target schema.
2. Create a stored procedure in your target schema, which creates database link per execute immediate
3. Call this procedure
4. Finally drop this procedure.